# Use the WP media uploader dialog for uploading a form attachment (non-admin). Offering progress and drag and drop feedback

Tags: uploads, attachments, media

I am building a simple contact form (non-admin) that has an attachment field. Of course I can just handle the upload via WP's wp_handle_upload function. However, I would like to give my visitors a more user friendly experience and manage the upload via wp's media upload "pop-up". Offering them upload progress feedback, drag'n drop etc. I know that this is normally admin only but is there a way to use this upload dialog for normal (non-registered, non-logged in) users?

I'm quite amazed that apparently no one really did this (after quite some searching).

Thanx!

Comment: What have you done so far yourself?

Comment: I've tried it with the normal approach (wp_enqueue_media(),  add jquery etc). This doesn't seem to work though. I figure its a rights / include issue.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer:* I guess it's not a real answer and has way to much outside links, but it just won't fit into the comment format. So this can be considered to be  just for information purposes.

---

I guess this

- [Add new media uploader at frontend for wp 3.5+](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/116489/22534)

uses about what you've already tried.

But there are possibilities, so you might just have to read a little bit more

- [How to call WP3.5 Media Library manager?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/82857/22534)
- [Using Wordpress 3.5 Media Uploader in meta box?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/75808/22534)
- [Using the WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader window as a modal popup](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/97056/22534)
- [Handling front-end file uploads, considering safety and ease of use](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/42068/22534)

For additional sources take a look at

- [How to use WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader in Theme Options](http://codestag.com/how-to-use-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-theme-options/)
- [Using the WordPress 3.5 Media Uploader within plugins](http://mikejolley.com/2012/12/using-the-new-wordpress-3-5-media-uploader-in-plugins/)
- [Adding an image uploader to the user profile page in WordPress](http://s2webpress.com/add-image-uploader-to-profile-admin-page-wordpress/)

This might be interesting too

- [How to use wp media uploader in a external non-wp page or in frontend](http://digitalzoomstudio.net/2013/09/17/how-to-use-wp-media-uploader-in-a-external-non-wp-page-or-in-frontend/)

Comment: Thanx for the lengthy response! Most of your resources refer to the normal wp-admin case though. However, the last link looks promising! In any case it looks like I need to work on my googely skills... :)